# How to combine multi tables into one sql statement

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 4 tables i want to join into one sql statement.

These are my tables:

1. **exp_members**: card_id (pk)
2. **transactions**: card_id(pk), restaurant_id(pk)
3. **exp_channel_data**: restaurant_id(pk)
4. **exp_channel_titles**:   restaurant_id(pk)

I already tried with a statement like this, but this did not work

```
    SELECT cm.*, t.*, cd.*, ct.*
FROM exp_members as cm
Inner JOIN transactions as t on (cm.card_id = t.restaurant_id)
Inner JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (ct.restaurant_id = t.restaurant_id)
Inner JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (cd.restaurant_id = ct.restaurant_id)
order by t.created DESC limit 50
```

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work? the records you see are not the expected results? or what?

Comment: How do you want them to join? A LEFT JOIN includes all the values from the table on the left (eg. transactions) hand side of the query regardless of a match.

Comment: **"did not work"** does not describes the expected behavior and the received results/errors

Comment: Why doesn't work? Do you got any error?

Comment: the first join is using ct, I think you should join before cm table

Comment: I want to know if the syntax is correct in sql statement, beacuse i dont get anything from my DB.

Comment: Can you show some sample data? My best guess, though, is that it's because you don't have anything joined to the `cm` table.

Comment: You should correctly join tables, otherwise there will wrong data, for example join transactions to exp_members by member id and so on step by step

Comment: I jsut updated my question. I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you put something like this:

```
SELECT t.*. cd.*, ct.*
FROM transactions as t
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.restaurant_id)
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (cd.entry_id = ct.entry_id)
WHERE t.cardid > 0 
and t.restaurant_id > 0
and ct.status= 'open'
order by t.created DESC limit 50
```

It give you something???.....i'm sorry but it's hard to find a simple solution without your tables structures :)

Saludos.